# Bootstrap alignment bug only occuring in internet explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, bootstrap-4, alignment

I have a bug on my website only occuring in the Internet Explorer and I cant find out how I can fix it. I already checked if there are any unclosed elements in my code.

In Chrome the elements are aligned correctly: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKlAd.png)

and in Internet explorer the elements are covering each other 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2ZvE.png)

This is my HTML code

```
  <div  class="hellgrau">
      <div class="kontaktcontainer container d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center kontakt">
            <i class="icon fa fa-phone fa-3x"></i>
            <h2>Telefon</h2>
              <hr class="pg-titl-bdr-btm">
                <p class="kontaktbereich"> Tel: 0211 - 205 444 80 <br> Fax:0211 - 205 444 81 </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center kontakt">
              <i class="icon text-center fa fa-envelope fa-3x"></i>

              <h2> Mail</h2>
                <hr class="pg-titl-bdr-btm">
                <a href="mailto:kontakt@mabs40.com?subject= TISAX Beratung">
                  <p class="kontaktbereich"> kontakt@mabs40.com <br>  </p>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center kontakt">
                <i class="icon fa fa-map-marker fa-3x"></i>
                <h2> Adresse</h2>
                  <hr class="pg-titl-bdr-btm">
              <p class="kontaktbereich">Großenbaumer Weg 8 <br> 40472 Düsseldorf</p>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and this my CSS:

```
.kontakt{
    padding-left: 80px;
    padding-right: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the [Bootstrap Flex](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_flex.asp), try to remove the "**d-flex**":

```
  <div  class="hellgrau">
      <div class="kontaktcontainer container justify-content-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center kontakt">
            <i class="icon fa fa-phone fa-3x"></i>
            <h2>Telefon</h2>
              <hr class="pg-titl-bdr-btm">
                <p class="kontaktbereich"> Tel: 0211 - 205 444 80 <br> Fax:0211 - 205 444 81 </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center kontakt">
              <i class="icon text-center fa fa-envelope fa-3x"></i>

              <h2> Mail</h2>
                <hr class="pg-titl-bdr-btm">
                <a href="mailto:kontakt@mabs40.com?subject= TISAX Beratung">
                  <p class="kontaktbereich"> kontakt@mabs40.com <br>  </p>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center kontakt">
                <i class="icon fa fa-map-marker fa-3x"></i>
                <h2> Adresse</h2>
                  <hr class="pg-titl-bdr-btm">
              <p class="kontaktbereich">Großenbaumer Weg 8 <br> 40472 Düsseldorf</p>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The result like this:

[image]